# Laravel Facebook login - no callback (localhost)

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5

My first question: is it possible to test this on a localhost? (Because I can imagine that this could be my problem)

I read the docs and did everything like it is described. I browser to /auth/facebook and I get redirected to Facebook where I "accept" the terms. I get redirected to this link: `http://localhost:8000/auth/login#_=_`

So I tried to debug and did a `dd($user);` in my Authcontroller, but there was no output given.

```
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        dd($user);

        // $user->token;
    }
```

Anyone an idea what I did wrong?

Comment: I have some ideas but to really know what's wrong I'd need to see your AuthController file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to see your routes configuration for more info, but will give it a shot with the info you provided.

Note that you are getting redirected to `http://localhost:8000/auth/login#_=_`.

**That looks like you are getting redirected to your app's login page after authorizing on facebook**.

In `config/services.php`, make sure that, for your facebook login configuration, your `redirect` url points to a route which you have defined in your routing configuration to handle the callback.

e.g.

```
// config/services.php
...

'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => 'my_facebook_client_id',
        'client_secret' => 'my_facebook_client_secret',
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback',
    ],

...
```

The route `http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback` should then be defined in the routing configuration:

```
// app/Http/routes.php
...

Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');

...
```

Note that the routing config has to allow `GET` requests since the user will be redirected.

Your `dd($user)` should work just fine with this setup.

---

How you save the user data depends on your model architecture.

For instance, in a simple case where you have no other registration method and only use facebook login, you could do this:

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $facebookData = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    // check if already in DB
    try{
        $user = User::where('facebook_id', $data->id)->firstOrFail();
    } catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        // create a new user
        $user = new User();

        // set the properties you want
        // $user->facebook_id = $data->id;
        // ...

        // then save
        $user->save();
    }

    // login the user
    Auth::login($user);

    // perhaps return a redirect response
    return redirect()->action('MyController@myAction');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I misinterpreted `'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback',` 
I thought it should've been the desired redirect url after the login succeeded.

Comment: You interpreted correctly. The redirect is indeed the desired redirect url after the login succeeds. The only problem is you don't want that URL to be your regular login page because you would be asking the user to log in after already logging in on facebook. 

Glad I could help. Cheers!

Comment: How do I put the user info in database & log them in? I can't find an example of that. :/

Comment: [@RW24](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4243855/rw24) I've updated the answer to show how you could do that.