# authentification facebook : Invalid App ID The provided App ID does not appear to be valid

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-authentication, laravel-socialite

i want to login with facebook, i create laravel authentication, i add button login with facebook, i install laravel socialite package by command composer require laravel/socialite, i add configuration in config/services:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/laravel-socialite/public/login/facebook/callback',
    ],
```

I added in routes/web.php the routes:

```
Route::get ('login/facebook',[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'redirectToFacebook'])->name('login.facebook');
Route::get('login/facebook/callback',[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class,'handleFacebookCallback']);
```

I put in the button "login with facebook" url:

```
<a href="{{ route('login.facebook') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">login with Facebook</a>
```

I put id and variable key in the .env file:

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID="1332763360453031"
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET="b459fd6252126609a1ad1a5d81161f1d"
```

I created the _registerOrLoginUser function in loginController:

```
protected function _registerOrLoginUser ($ data)
    {
        $ user = User :: where ('email', '=', $ data-> email) -> first ();
        if (! $ user) {
            $ user = new User ();
            $ user-> name = $ data-> name;
            $ user-> email = $ data-> email;
            $ user-> provider_id = $ data-> provider_id;
            $ user-> avatar = $ data-> avatar;
            $ user-> save ();
        }
        Auth :: login ($ user);
    }
```

I added the two function in LoginController.php and called the _registerOrLoginUser function and redirect to "home".

```
public function redirectToFacebook () {
            return Socialite :: driver ('google') -> redirect ();
        }
        public function handleFacebookCallback () {
            $ user = Socialite :: driver ('facebook') -> user ();
            $ this -> _ registerOrLoginUser ($ user);
            return redirect () -> route ('home');
        }
```

I created google application to get id and sercret.

database/table users migrations:

```
public function up ()
    {
        Schema :: create ('users', function (Blueprint $ table) {
            $ table-> id ();
            $ table-> string ('name');
            $ table-> string ('email');
            $ table-> timestamp ('email_verified_at') -> nullable ();
            $ table-> string ('password');
            $ table-> string ('provider_id') -> nullable ();
            $ table-> string ('avatar') -> nullable ();
            $ table-> rememberToken ();
            $ table-> timestamps ();
        });
    }
```

and finally when I click on the login button with facebook it opens facebook page with an `invalid app ID` message
`The application ID provided does not appear to be valid`.
in link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Faswaktin%2Fpublic%2Flogin%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=mxWJ2fjpUyAqvhs6o88V3wOJXjkBBZdbU3MCbirY
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the laravel server.
Use **php artisan serve** to start laravel application.

Review your redirect URL in facebook developer account and in your facebook config file.

You should check this question.
[Laravel Facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33208999/16509073)